# Command line command to copy a file inside the subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Using the command line, I'd like to copy one file to a list of folders simultaneously.
For example, I want to copy `E:\HTM.nsf` to:

```
E:\Note\A1\note\data1\
E:\Note\A2\note\data1\
E:\Note\A3\note\data1\
E:\Note\A4\note\data1\
```

I use XCopy:

```
E:\>xcopy e:\HTM*.*nsf "\notes\A1\note\data1\"
```

Its works, but i want to copy `HTM.nsf` to all users (A1 to A4) at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like you will need a batch file to get this solved. How do you want to maintain the list of target paths? Do you want to store them in batch variables or in a text file?

Comment: batch file going to be fine . Try this and didn't work .
for /E %%1 in (E:\Note\*) DO copy "E:\HTM.nsf" %%1\note\data1 /Y

Comment: Thanks for the hint, with this information I was able to create a batch ... please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a batch script `copyfiles.cmd` like this one:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%1"=="/restart" goto restart
for /d %%a in (
  "E:\Note\A*"
) do (call %0 /restart %%~fa\note\data1)
goto end

:restart
shift
set targetPath="%1"
echo processing %targetPath% ...
copy e:\HTM*.*nsf %targetPath% /B/Y
exit /b

:end
exit
```

**Notes:**

- the path needs to be split, you cannot use the wildcard `*` in the middle of a path
- by using the `E:\Note\A*` path in the loop, it finds A1, A2, A3 and so on, the rest of the path is appended, i.e. the expression `%%~fa\note\data1` is used to complete the path (where `%%~fa` is a placeholder for one of the paths found - e.g. `E:\Note\A1`)
- this script starts itself, the copy command occurs at the label `:restart` and returns to the for loop by using `exit /b`